# Java Cast String to Date

Tags: postgresql, spring-mvc, dao

How can I cast a `java.lang.String` to a `java.sql.Date` to get the following value: `'12/03/2016'`?

I tried this:

```
@Override
public int insertNewApplication(StudenDetails sd)
{
    String sql = "INSERT INTO student_details"
            + "(applicant_name, applsex, "
            + "designation, date_of_superannuation, "
            + "ou_code, residential_address, "
            + "phone_no, mobile_no,email_id,token_user_id,token_password, "
            + "staff_status,office_type_code) VALUES (?, ?, ?,to(?,'DD/MM/YYYY'), ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?,?)";

    return jdbcTemplate.update(sql, new Object[] {
            tpd.getApplicant_name(), tpd.getApplsex(),tpd.getDesignation(),tpd.getDate_of_superannuation(),tpd.getOu_code(),tpd.getResidential_address(),tpd.getPhone_no(),tpd.getMobile_no(),
            tpd.getEmail_id(),tpd.getToken_user_id(),tpd.getToken_password(),tpd.getStaff_status(),tpd.getOffice_type_code()
            });

}
```

Comment: Please be more specific. What is your problem? What are you trying to achieve? Please edit the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's isn't a standard way that's widely accepted between RDBMSs on converting strings to dates. In Postgres, which you tagged, you could use the `to_date` function:

```
to_date(?, 'DD/MM/YY')
```

A better approach, IMHO, would be to do this conversion in Java, making your application much more portable:

```
private static final SimpleDateFormat FORMAT_CONVERTER = 

@Override
public int insertNewApplication(StudenDetails sd)
{
    String sql = "INSERT INTO student_details"
            + "(applicant_name, applsex, "
            + "designation, date_of_superannuation, "
            + "ou_code, residential_address, "
            + "phone_no, mobile_no,email_id,token_user_id,token_password, "
            + "staff_status,office_type_code) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?,?)";
    Date date = FORMAT_CONVERTER.parse(tpd.getDate_of_superannuation());

    return jdbcTemplate.update(sql, new Object[] {
            tpd.getApplicant_name(), tpd.getApplsex(),tpd.getDesignation(),date,tpd.getOu_code(),tpd.getResidential_address(),tpd.getPhone_no(),tpd.getMobile_no(),
            tpd.getEmail_id(),tpd.getToken_user_id(),tpd.getToken_password(),tpd.getStaff_status(),tpd.getOffice_type_code()
            });
}
```